# How can I use auto-implemented properties with just the 'set' accessor and not using the 'get' accessor?

Tags: c#, properties, accessor

In c#, I recently learned that auto-implemented properties can make things easier since it automatically declares a backing private field for us.

Using both the 'get' and 'set' accessors or just the 'get' accessor in the auto-implemented properties to make it read-only was possible, and no errors occured.  However, using only the 'set' accessor to make the property write-only resulted in a error.

**[accessor must declare a body because property is not marked as 'abstract' or 'extern']**

I have no idea why this error occurs. It probably wants me to explicitly create the backing field myself, but that's not the auto-implemented properties are for. Can anyone tell me how to solve this issue, or what I have mistaken?

```
namespace ConsoleApp1;

public static class AutoImplementedPropTest
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        
    }
}

class C
{
    public int A { set; }
}

class D
{
    public int A { get; set; }
}

class E
{
    private int a;

    public int A
    {
        set
        {
            a = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I wrote. No errors in class D and E but only in C.

Comment: Just declare a private getter

Comment: While you *can* do this, in reality it rarely makes sense to have a set-only property; in the few scenarios where people suggest them, an explicit operation like `SetA(int value)` is usually clearer; this is subjective and contextual, note

Comment: What is the point in setting a property that you can never read?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Maybe you're right. I will never use such in actual programming. It's just for testing though..